# error generating dynamic reconfigure .h files

Tags: catkin-make, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I am migrating a package from rosmake to catkin. So far I've been sucessfull. The only problem is that, I don't know why, when it generates de dynamic reconfigure configuration files (the ones ending in Config.h in the case of c++) are not stored in devel/include/PACKAGE_NAME/. What it actually happends is that it apperars folder within the src of the package with the name of the package containing the python for the dynamic reconfigure and another one in the folder wher I have the configuration file for generating the dynamic reconfigure options called cpp where the .h file is stored.

I've been able to reproduce the same problem with [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/subw9x54454iuk2/test.tar.gz?dl=0) test package. Could you help me?

Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237568/error-generating-dynamic-reconfigure-.h-files/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2016-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you change to using the catkin version of the parameter generator?

```
from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator_catkin import *
```

That part of the catkin migration is easy to overlook. (I did.)

See: http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/dynamic_reconfiguration.html

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on 2016-06-21**:
Thank you. That was the problem!